# Image tag in svg pattern definition is not accepting an svg format image

Tags: svg

The following HTML code renders me a pattern that contains an image of type `.svg` inside another SVG.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <svg width="0px" height="0px">
      <defs>
        <pattern id="saint1729" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="8" height="8" fill="#ff7156">
          <image xlink:href="http://saint1729.me/tiny-checkered-pattern.svg" x="0" y="0" width="8" height="8" />
        </pattern>
      </defs>
    </svg>
    <div>
      <svg width="240" height="16">
        <path d="M0 0 H240 V16 H0 Z" fill="url(#saint1729)"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I changed the image attribute href inside pattern to direct `SVG` tag (which is coming from the same URL), I don't see anything rendered. Here's the code for this scenario.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <svg width="0px" height="0px">
      <defs>
        <pattern id="saint1729" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="8" height="8" fill="#ff7156">
          <image xlink:href="<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='8' height='8' viewBox='0 0 8 8'><g fill='#c82c0e' fill-opacity='1'><path fill-rule='evenodd' d='M0 0h4v4H0V0zm4 4h4v4H4V4z'/></g></svg>" x="0" y="0" width="8" height="8" />
        </pattern>
      </defs>
    </svg>
    <div>
      <svg width="240" height="16">
        <path d="M0 0 H240 V16 H0 Z" fill="url(#saint1729)"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What is the difference between the two? How to make the second approach work?

I am using **Google Chrome** browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However this is working. You need to encode the svg. I use this [SVG encoder](https://codepen.io/yoksel/pen/JDqvs). Also please read this post: [Optimizing SVGs in data URIs](https://codepen.io/tigt/post/optimizing-svgs-in-data-uris)

```html
<svg width="0px" height="0px">
      <defs>
        <pattern id="saint1729" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="8" height="8" fill="#ff7156">
          <image xlink:href="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='8' height='8' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cg fill='%23c82c0e' fill-opacity='1'%3E%3Cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M0 0h4v4H0V0zm4 4h4v4H4V4z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E" x="0" y="0" width="8" height="8" />
        </pattern>
      </defs>
    </svg>
    <div>
      <svg width="240" height="16">
        <path d="M0 0 H240 V16 H0 Z" fill="url(#saint1729)"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
```